# JBoss Login module to quarkus

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, quarkus

we have an jboss jsf web application with login module configured in the standalone.xml.

```
<security-domain name="my-domain" cache-type="default">
 <authentication>
  <login-module code="com.my.login.CoreLoginModule" flag="required">
   <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-1"/>
  </login-module>
 </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

So, we want to migrate the web application to quarkus. But we can not configure the login in quarkus. It is clear, there is no standalone.xml in quarkus but we have no idea where to define the login module which is called when this is called in the code during login.

```
httpServletRequest.login(username, password);
```

Can anyone help us, thanks.

Comment: Quarkus doesn't support login modules, so you will have to reimplement that. Here's the Quarkus security introduction and signpost: https://quarkus.io/guides/security

Comment: Ok, that was my fear. That means i have to implement my own login mechanism?